# Access blob storage from webapp (azure)

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to put an application to production on Azure. This application consists of a webapp (running a Docker container) that is supposed to communicate with an Azure Storage Account (blob).

After adding all outbound IP Adresses of the web app to the firewall settings of my storage account, I still have no permission to access the blobs. The error is the following:
"This request is not authorized to perform this operation."

However, when I run my app in local and add my local IP to these same firewall settings, it works. When I do not add it to the firewall settings, I get the same error. I therefore believe my storage account does not allow traffic coming from my webapp whilst it should.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks,

Clank

Comment: Hello @clank , may I know if the web app uses managed identity?if it uses then can you try adding the storage blob data contributor role to it ..

Comment: Do you need write access to Blob storage?

Comment: Hello @AnsumanBal-MT, yes I will try this way but I don't have the required rights to try this yet though. Thank you!

Comment: Hello @CSharpRocks, yes I do need write access.

Comment: OK, that rules out the Path Mapping to Blob feature because it's read only.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Is it possible to change this? What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of Managed identity to provide access to storage blob from web app.

You need to assign 'Storage Blob Data contributor' access to webapp. You can follow below steps for the same.

Storage Account -> Access Control (IAM) -> Grant Access to this resource -> 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' -> Select resource (web app)